# Git Checkout Using Pathspec with Wildcard

Tags: git, path, branch, wildcard, git-checkout

I would like to restore some files in the working directory to the state of the latest commit on the current local branch, which is `master`, however, my attempts to use git checkout to achieve this have failed consistently.

I have confirmed that the following works:
`git checkout HEAD src/graphql/User.ts`

But I know that I should be able to use a wildcard in the pathspec, i.e. :
`git checkout HEAD '*/User.ts'`

However this fails.

How can I use a pathspec with a wildcard to restore a limited set of files to the state stored in the latest or previous commit?

Comment: `*/User.ts` will only match one level. Like `src/User.ts`

Comment: Good point, how can I match on all levels? 
`git checkout HEAD '**/User.ts'` gives me the same error, although it seems to be the correct usage based on (https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#def_pathspec).

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, there are two solutions to this problem.

1. Git has shipped a new feature called `restore` which allows for the use of a pathspec. See (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore). So

> `git restore */User.ts`

will work.

2. The following will work as well, although I'm not quite sure why:

> `git checkout -- '*/User.ts'`

Comment: Remember that it's not the git command responsible for shell expansions, but the shell you are using.

Comment: Note that `git checkout -- <pathspec>` means *extract from the index*, while `git checkout HEAD -- <pathspec>` means *extract from the current commit*.